# How to add a background to a logo?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, layers, background

[image]

Can someone explain to me how to put the picture of the pink (marble) background inside the round shape?

Comment: Hi user70650, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the help center or ping one of us in the Graphic Design Chat once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site! Is the logo a flattened image or is it an editable graphic? Hint: Clipping Mask... FYI, I would suggest you do not title posts with all caps.

Comment: I tried the cropping tool but it didn't work. I am very new to this website and to adobe illustrator thank you for the help! This website is very useful for newbies like me on adobe illustrator. I tried the clipping mask and it works like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you've made the logo in illustrator you could simply copy your outer circle, place your new circle over the top of your image and create a clipping mask. In the menu "Object > Clipping Mask > Make" or "Command + 7" on a mac.

Place your new clipped texture under your first circle and make sure your first circle doesn't have a fill.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I did tried the clipping mask. I am quite new to adobe illustrator. I tried cropping a round shape but it didn't work. The clipping mask works well!

Comment: Great - glad it worked for you :)